# JMeter regular expression extractor i want to check when the webpage has completed shows the completed text

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter. I am using the Regular Extraction extractor as i want to check when the text "Completed" appears on the webpage.
On the page I click a run button. 
The page will process some data & show a progress bar.
I have used the recorder to capture all the steps from login to the processing page.
The processing takes time to complete and I want to check when the complete message appears.
This way I know the processing has completed as i am testing how long the processing takes with x number of users for this page.
I have put the regular expression extractor in a While loop controller.

The Regular expression extractor i have set the following values:

Reference Name: Completed

Regular Expression:  div class=""gwt-Label absoluteleft padding">[Completed]

Template: $1$

DefaultValue: None

I have inspected the web page and the html content shown is:

```
<tdbody>
<tr>
<td>     
<div class=""gwt-Label absoluteleft padding">Completed.</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tdbody>
```

Have i done my regular expression correctly to check for the completed message appears?

I think i am doing the test the wrong as it looks like the while controller is stuck in an infinite loop.

My set up is like this:

```
Thread Group
- HTTP Request Defaults
- HTTP Cookie Manager
-Recording controller
- http requests (login, select project, go to processing page, run process)
- While controller
- http request (the page which does the processing)
- regular expression extractor
- Constant timer
```

In the While controller i have tried setting the Condition field to the value Completed.
I run it, it never exits the loop.

I think maybe i need an assertion to check when the completed message appears then it will exit.
I understand the While loop will keep running while true.  When the condition is false then it will exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the condition in your while controller?  The while controller can be very difficult when it comes to the condition.  You can try:

```
${__javaScript("${Completed}" == "Completed")}
```

or

```
${__javaScript("${Completed}" != "Completed")}
```

depending on whether you want the While controller to execute when the action has been completed or while it has not.

Comment: I had just put the reference name "completed" in the while controller Condition field.  I will try the Javascript function.  Thanks.

Comment: While the page is processing the data, i want to wait for the completed message.  Then my test can exit, finish.  The http request (the page which processes the data) I have put under the while controller.  As the page will stay here until the processing has completed.